# Creating my username and password for bitcoin

Tags: passwords, bitcoin

I'm reading this [article](http://www.newslobster.com/random/how-to-get-started-using-your-gpu-to-mine-for-bitcoins-on-windows) for Windows Bitcoin mining

Now, it tells me I need to create a Username and Password, but, when I run the batch, it says:

> Wrong Username or Password

How does the Bitcoin client know my password?  How do I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the rpcuser and rpcpass settings in your [bitcoin.conf](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) file.  It should be located in either `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin` or `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\Bitcoin`.

Note that unless you have a really high hash rate (multiple computers with multiple video cards each), you're probably better off doing pooled mining instead of solo mining.  Instead of having your mining program connect to the bitcoin client on your computer, you would have it connect to the pool's servers.  I haven't used GUIminer, but I believe it's preconfigured to allow you to connect to one of several popular pools.

Comment: I didn't ask for your opinion on whether I should mine or not.  Thanks though for the answer.

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't mine.  You should just be aware that at the current difficulty level, a single Radeon 5870 running at 400 MH/s will take an average of 30 weeks to find a single block when solo mining.  That doesn't account for future difficulty increases either.  When doing pooled mining, on the other hand, you get a proportional reward every time the pool finds a block.